# How do I enable GPU support in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am quite new to tensorflow so I was following along with this guide to setting up tensorflow on windows:

https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-jul-2020.ipynb

All goes well, but my output to the test script he put at the bottom returns:

```
Tensor Flow Version: 2.3.0
Keras Version: 2.4.0

Python 3.8.13 (default, Mar 28 2022, 06:59:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas 1.2.4
Scikit-Learn 1.0.2
GPU is NOT AVAILABLE
```

I am unsure why my GPU is not available. My hardware is AMD ryzen 5 3600, msi b550 pro a, corsair vengeance lpx 16 gb and msi rtx 2060

Comment: Is "msi rtx 2060" your graphics card? And is it an NVIDIA card?

Comment: I believe so, here is a link to the card: https://www.msi.com/Graphics-Card/GeForce-RTX-2060-GAMING-Z-6G

Comment: Did you install just `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`?

Comment: i installed tensorflow-gpu via conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Are you on Linux? Did you install GPU drivers? I recommend to follow the official tensorflow installation instructions.

Comment: @RayyanS, Please follow the instructions as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu). Thanks!